Decals not working with instanced meshes, in Three.js
Been dabbling around with decals for a while. While it works like a charm with normal meshes, it doesn’t work with instanced meshes. How can I make it work with an instanced mesh? Does it require modifications to the source code?
const decals = [];

document.addEventListener('pointerdown', (e) => {
    const windowX = e.clientX;
    const windowY = e.clientY;
    const ndcX = ((windowX / window.innerWidth) * 2) - 1;
    const ndcY = -((windowY / window.innerHeight) * 2) + 1;
    
    raycaster.setFromCamera(new THREE.Vector2(ndcX, ndcY), camera);
    const intersections = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);
    console.log(intersections);
    if (intersections.length) {
        // get the first object you intersect with
        const intersectedInstance = intersections[0];
        const { face: { normal }, object, point, instanceId } = intersectedInstance;
        
        // get the instance transformation matrix 
        const instanceMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
        instancedMesh.getMatrixAt(instanceId, instanceMatrix);

        const worldInstanceMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
        worldInstanceMatrix.multiplyMatrices(instanceMatrix, instancedMesh.matrixWorld);
        ///

        const dummy = new THREE.Object3D();
        const n = normal.clone();
        n.transformDirection( worldInstanceMatrix );
        n.add(point.clone());

        dummy.position.copy( point.clone() );
        dummy.lookAt( n );

        const  size = new THREE.Vector3( 1, 1, 1.0);
        
        const decalGeometry = new DecalGeometry( object, point, dummy.rotation, size ); 
        const decalMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, depthWrite: false, polygonOffset: true, polygonOffsetFactor: - 4, depthTest: false} );
                        
        const decal = new THREE.Mesh( decalGeometry, decalMaterial );
        decals.push(decal);
        decal.renderOrder = decals.length;

        scene.add(decal);
        

    }


});

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Here’s a jsfiddle link for your reference:
https://jsfiddle.net/sk3tjzpg/1/ . Reference to earlier question : Decal geometry not appearing on instancedmesh in Three.js

Just a suggestion: Clarify the question titles. They both read as very similar, but the specifics are different. Be clear with what makes them unique so others don't think they are (or accidentally flag them as) duplicates.
